# android - onLocationChanged never called

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, location, on-location-changed

I am currently implementing a feature of getting user's current location with Google API.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); // user location center in map (every update)
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    }
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }else{

    }
}
```

However, onLocationChanged callback function is never triggered when I requestLocationUpdates in onConnected. I have log several status out, showing that mLocationRequest is created and requestLocationUpdates is called.

Any ideas on this? Thank you all!

Comment: what are the values for `DISPLACEMENT`, `UPDATE_INTERVAL` and `FASTEST_INTERVAL` in your code? Please try with a low value for each..for testing, you can use `0` for those 3...

Comment: Are you sure you have valid permissions?

Comment: I have included :<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> in my Android Manifest.

Comment: You probably have to go outside for GPS to work and even wait for a while for a GPS satellite fix.